# Windows RT will not reset/refresh/install apps

Tags: windows-rt

Here's the situation.

A family member has the Lumia 2520, a simply brilliant creation by Nokia. I have added an SD card to expand memory and pointed all the libraries, including OneDrive to that location - works fine. I have also optimized the `WinSXS` folder (using the `Services` task) so that I have an inconceivable 6.x GB free space on the primary drive - on a system typically plagued with low disk space. Finally, I have successfully updated with every possible Windows update, including the Windows 10 look-a-like update from last month.

So far so good, right?

But, apps wont install from the Windows Store. I have cleared the /user `packages` cache and even deleted the installation folder(s) under `WindowsApps`. When I run the Windows Store, it recognizes the missing app and gives me the option to install them. Only they never appear in the All Apps list, and manually executing them from the file system also never works.

After this strange state is achieved, the Windows Store still reports them as installed and no longer gives me the option to install them (or re-install them). Only after using `WsReset.exe` does the Windows Store seem to not think they are installed anymore and give me the option to install them again - only to not show up in the App List again.

Time to reset, right?

There are two types of resetting. The type that keeps your files, and the kind that basically starts from scratch. At this point, I would be willing to accept either. But neither works. Both report that the media is missing and cannot continue. At first I thought it was a lack of space. That's what drove me to add the SD card. No luck. Then I thought it was a lack of updates, but I am 100% positive every possible update has been successfully installed.

Getting the "original media" for a Windows RT device is nearly impossible except, perhaps, for the Surface RT which Microsoft makes publically available on their web site. Every other device has a chipset-specific build of Windows RT and, as a result, we cannot re-use media from one device for another. I have looked and looked, and this is not an uncommon situation for 2520 owners, yet nobody seems to know how or where to locate the original media for a reset.

So, one fear in the back of my mind is that I mistakenly brick this machine. If it were my tablet, I might be slightly more cavalier. But this belongs to someone else and I don't want to be responsible for this device if it fails.

Pretend you are me. What would you do next?

Comment: Lumia 2520 has a chipset specifically build also.  The original Surface RT and Surface 2 both also had a  chipset specific builds of `Windows RT` also.  Its not clear how we can help you, we are limited, there isn't a public .ISO.  Have you contacted Nokia/Microsoft for assistance in this matter?

Comment: Your problems with not being able to reset are likely because of your changes to the WinSxS folder.